# Поставщик "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" не зарегистрирован на локальном компьютере

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Как решать эту проблему ?

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Вызываем окно проводника
    OpenFileDialog opfd = new OpenFileDialog();

    // Если выбрали, то загружаем
    if (opfd.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {

        if (opfd.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx")) {
            // on crée une connexion vers le fichier excel reste à trouver son chemin et de modifier la partie rouge...
            OleDbConnection Excel = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=test.xlsx;
            Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";");

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Feuil1$]", Excel); // l'étoile (*) permet d'importer l'ensemble du fichier Excel
            // j'ouvre la connexion 
            Excel.Open();
            DataTable tableau = new DataTable();
            OleDbDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            tableau.Load(Reader);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = tableau;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: Это не помогает.

Comment: Сталкивался с данной проблемой, мне помогло https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 1):

Возможные причины данной ошибки:

1. Не установлен [Microsoft Access 2010 Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/EN-US/DOWNLOAD/DETAILS.ASPX?ID=13255) или полноценный Microsoft Access
2. Разрядность приложения не совпадает с разрядностью установленного Database Engine (или Access).